# Why passing the req.params in find query doesn't work in node js/mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First of all these are the files:

MySchema File which has two reference variables as well

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Creating Schema
const userShelfSchema = new Schema({
    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'userModel'
    },
    bookShelf:[{
        bookId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'bookDetailsModel'
        },
        status:{
            type: String
        },
        rating:{
            type: Number
        },
        review:{
            type: String
        },
        date:{
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now 
        }
   }]
})

module.exports = userShelfModel = mongoose.model('userShelfModel', userShelfSchema);
```

So I want to find all the users which have a specific book in their bookShelf array, so to that I have the following code in my bookdetails.js:

```
router.get('/reviews/:bookid', (req, res) =>{


   userShelf.find({bookShelf:{bookId:req.params.bookid}})
            .populate('user',['name']) 
            .then(reviews=>{
                return res.json({reviews});
            })
            .catch(err=>res.status(400).json({error:"server error"}));
        
});
```

I am getting no errors here but I just keep getting a null array, I looked up on Mongo docs but couldn't find anything, also I tried to pass the params.bookid as a `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` but that also returns a null value. what should I change in my code ? please help.

Comment: have you tried: `{ 'bookShelf.bookId': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.bookid)}` ?

Comment: yeah I did that but it doesn't filter the output instead returns every object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried a lot of stuff but I just couldn't find the perfect solution, turns out the problem is that BookId is an object and req.params.bookid is string and the result of comparing them is always false, so instead of finding the bookId using the Mongo's find() method I wrote my own logic to get the reviews by BookId, I know this isn't the perfect solution and only a workaround, so untill some one in future finds an answer to this I'll mark this one as the correct answer, so here's the code anyways:

```
router.get('/reviews/:bookid', (req, res) =>{
   userShelf.find()
            .then(result=>{
                reviews=[];
                for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                    reviews[i] = result[i].bookShelf.map((x=>{
                        if(x.bookId.toString() === req.params.bookid){
                            return x.review;
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }));
                }
                finalreviews = reviews.flat().filter(x=>x);
                return res.json({finalreviews});
            })
            .catch(err=>res.status(400).json({error:"server error"}));
        
});
```